# How to import string values (x, y, z) for generating geometry in three.js?

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I am newbie in javascript three.js and at the moment I am working on project, where I would like to import string values (x, y, z) into a three.js file for generating cubes or spheres with the values. The values are transformed from a json file into ASCII numeric values.
Sofar with my script I get in console this output:
x= 912 y= 500 z= 327

How can I write a script to uses these values for creating cubes, spheres or other geometry in three.js?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with what you already have?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with it, but how can I generate with these values new geometry in three.js?

Comment: If your question has nothing to do with this code then don't post this code, or people will spend time looking over it for issues, like I just did.  Post a question explaining exactly what you're trying to do, with a **_minimal_** amount of code to show an example of your problem.

Comment: thanks for the advise! will reformulate my post and try my best to explain my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is make another variable in the JSON called: 'type', based on this type you make your geometry (BoxGeometry, SphereGeometry).

With a sphere, you can only set the radius if you still want to use the Y and Z axis you can scale the sphere. Or use them as the position in your scene.

Regards

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback! I am going to try it out.

Comment: if you have any other questions please feel free to look me up on the three js slack channel - https://threejs.slack.com/